# How do I force analog audio via the 3.5 jack when Pi 4 is headless?

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I am deploying a Pi 4 on a wheelchair and require audio output to prompt the user.  The Pi is headless (i.e. no monitor).  On the bench, with a monitor, my code correctly sends the audio out the 3.5 jack to a powered amplifier.  When I unplug the HDMI cable and reboot, the audio stops working.  Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

I set the output to analog via the sound icon on the monitor.  Could it bed that the Pi forgets the setting when no monitor is connected?  Or, does the Pi look for HDMI before analog and hang? Or, do I need to set the sound level manually since the desktop is not working without the monitor?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.  Rick

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following into config.txt and reboot the Pi.

```
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1
audio_pwm_mode=2
```

The first line tells the Pi to ignore whatever HDMI thinks it's capability is and use the on-board audio.

The second line tries to take out some hiss and noise - it may not work for your audio but worth trying.

Make sure that these are in a section that gets read as config.txt can have sections depending on model, serial number etc.

Comment: And if you feel uncomfortable to edit text files there is the command line tool `raspi-config` . And to utilize it just SSH into your raspberry pi and run `raspi-config` if you need to change the settings in the future. Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Answer (score 1):

This answer may come too late for Mr. Foulds, but let me disgorge my
research here.

It seems the canonical way to choose the audio output on the RPi is to
use the raspi-config, which is an interactive menuing system.  Like
Mr. Foulds, I have a project where I would like the analog audio to be
the default.  You cannot use raspi-config at boot (unless you want to
use something like expect, but please do not).

A look at the source code for raspi-config provides the answer:

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config#L1968

All it does is configure the .asoundrc file for the current user
(usually pi for RPis).  Notice that what really changes is the 'card'
property in the pcm.output and ctl.!default blocks.  But how do we know
which "card" is the analog output?

Use 'aplay -l | grep bcm2835'.  That shows you all available cards.

Use your favorite unix pattern matching tool to extract the card
number.  Here's my example:

```
   aplay -l | grep bcm2835 | grep "Headphones" | perl -lane 'print substr($F[1],0,1)'
```

This will emit the card number of the "headphones" card.

Simply create the **.asoundrc** file with this card number at boot time.
There is already a template for this file in the raspi-config source
linked above.  I would use that.

You can change this RC file at any time.  When the linux sound system
needs to route audio output, it appears to consult this file.  No
rebooting is needed.  If you would like to read more about the linux
sound architecture, here is the wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture

I did a lot of web searches, but could not find this answer stated
clearly. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following option to `/boot/config.txt` fixed my analog audio issues:

```
dtparam=audio=on
```

And after that my system seems to default to the 3.5mm headphone audio input regardless.