# Headphone deactivates when RasPi is started without screen (HDMI)

Tags: audio, hdmi, screen

To my Rasbian setup I have a set of speakers connected via the headphone jack and it works just fine when I start the RasPi (3b+) with a connected HDMI screen, also when accessing it via a web portal (Phoniebox). When I disconnect the screen with the RasPi running, still everything works. However, when I restart the RasPi in headless mode the HDMI screen disconnected it goes silent. I can see from the phoniebox web application that songs are not played when I hit play.

I assume that the audio ouput is switched to HDMI as soon as I disconnect the screen? Is there a way the check this assumption?

Comment: Will this help https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118794/how-do-i-force-analog-audio-via-the-3-5-jack-when-pi-4-is-headless/118796#118796

Comment: Thanks just my issue (however not the solution )

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If I connect the Pi (4B, latest update-version) via HDMI-Cable to my TV, the audio-output is normal and I can switch it to Analog (3.5) and HDMI. But if I only connect my active-speaker, restart the Pi without connect via HDMI, it shows "no audio device found".

Is it possible to install an older Version of Raspbian, to be sure that this issue isn't a bug in the latest Raspian-version?

I want to built an alarmclock, which only should use the audio output with headphone jack.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please raise your own question rather than add questions to others.  Older versions of Raspberry Pi O/S and Raspbian can be found in the archives at https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/

Comment: I solved it with 

"sudo cp ~/.asoundrc /etc/asound.conf && sudo service mpd restart && mpc play"

What it didn't solve was the noise coming through the jack. I ordered an hdmi to 3,5mm jack adapter and that worked much better.